# How could I show $\langle Px,y\rangle=\langle x,Py\rangle$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$

Tags: functional-analysis

One of the problems in my functional analysis problem sheet asks me to show that P is a projection operator on a Hilbert space then , it is bounded and $\|P\|=1$ and $P=P^2$ and $\langle Px,y\rangle=\langle x,Py\rangle$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$ where $\langle \cdot\ ,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. I am stuck on the last part. I mean if we had $R^n$ then a projection operator is symmetric and I can use the natural definition of a the scalar product of two vectors to show that the equality holds. But I how could I show this in this case. I have spent quite some time thinking about it, but I am stuck. Any hints would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How do you define the projection operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, I should have read the question properly; you wanted a hint. I'm hoping you didn't read my full answer yet, and here is the hint. Try considering the subspace $V=PH$, and its orthogonal complement $V^\perp$, and try writing things like $x$ and $Px$ in terms of elements of these subspaces. How does this sort of representation affect the inner product calculation?

Comment: I am so sorry for the late response. Thank you for the hint. So we have that $\langle x,Py \rangle =\langle Px+ x^{\perp},Py \rangle=\langle Px,Py \rangle $ We can similarly claim that $\langle Px,y \rangle=\langle Px,Py \rangle$ which implies that $\langle x ,Py \rangle=\langle Px,y \rangle$ This is because $x^{\perp} \in U^{\perp}$ is orthogonal to any vector in $Px \in U$ with $x \in \mathcal{H}$  Right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reasoning or possibly notation. Why should your very first equality hold? My calculation before had $x=v+v^\perp$. Then $Px=v$ and $(1-P)x=v^\perp$. Does that help?

Comment: The first equality holds because by the projection lemma I can uniquely write any vector $x \in \mathcal{x}$ as  the sum of its projection onto the closed subspace $U$ i.e $ Px$ and an element $ x^{\perp}$in $U^{\perp}$

Comment: OK, I see. I misunderstood your notation.

Answer (score 1):

In general $<Px,y>=<x,P^*y>$ with $P^*$ the adjoint of $P$. But $<Px,y>=<x,Py>$ for all $x,y$ implies that $P=P^*$, i.e. $P$ is self-adjoint (an orthogonal projection operator).  Note that a general projection operator need not be self-adjoint, the first two properties suffice.